# C# Adding new rows in DataGridView and database (Access)

Tags: c#, sql, database, ms-access, datagridview

I am working on a billing form and i plan to do it in DataGridView to display the Item Name, Quantity, Price, etc. In addition to that, I also intend to add button controls such as snacks and drinks, which would automatically add rows into the DataGridView when selected. My DataGridView is binded to a DataSource. My question is, how do i go about achieving (a) Automatically adding rows into DataGridView after selecting a Beverage from any Beverage button and (b) Inserting these records into the database as well. Any sort of guidance will be greatly appreciated, cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Datatable dynamically make it as datasource

[Check this link for creating datatable dynamically](http://dotnetperls.com/datatable)

after creating it add

```
datagrid.DataSource=dt;
```